# Interpretation of $\int_\gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am following Stein's text and there is a minor detail which I cannot figure out. Suppose $\gamma$ is some (not necessarily closed) curve. In Stein's text he claims $\int_\gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz$

> "can be interpreted as the change in the argument of $f$ as $z$
> traverses the curve $\gamma$. Moreover, assuming the curve is closed,
> this change of argument is determined entirely by the zeros and poles
> of $f$ inside $\gamma$"

If $\gamma$ is closed it is clear why the change of argument interpretation holds, but I cannot see how or why this holds for any continuous curve $\gamma$, as the above quote suggests. Every other resource I have come across has the additional assumption that $\gamma$ must be closed.

I have already checked out [Interpretation of the Argument Principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686384/interpretation-of-the-argument-principle) and [Argument principle and change of argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2808631/argument-principle-and-change-of-argument), but am still not clear on the matter.

Comment: technically should be indeed $\Delta \arg f=\Im \int_\gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz$ as one can have a change in the modulus of $f$ given by the real part ( $\Delta \log |f|= \Re \int_\gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz$) ; if the curve is closed the change in modulus is zero, so the usual argument principle holds

Comment: @Conrad So for a strict change of argument it follows that $\gamma$ must be closed?

Comment: Even for a non-closed curve, the imaginary part of the integral gives the change in argument, but the integral may have a non zero real part too (giving the change in modulus); in the closed case, the real part is zero, so the integral gives only the change in argument and nothing else

Comment: @Conrad Ah I see that makes sense, so the change of argument follows from the imaginary part of the integral. Thanks!